# Control 'ctl02' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I get that error when trying to generate a number of buttons programmatically. I have no ctl02.. Why do i get that mistake?

```
  Button pgs = new Button();//Create New Topic
                        pgs.Width = 20;                        
                        pgs.Command += obtainTopicsPerPage_Click;
                        pgs.CommandName = tPage.ToString();
                        pgs.Text = tPage.ToString();

                        btns.Add(tPage.ToString());
                        buttons.Add(pgs);
```

I create a few buttons and loop through the list (buttons). Then i get that mistake :(. ... why?

Full design:

```
int maximumTopicPages;
int tPage;
int questionNumber=1;
Dictionary<string, List<DisplayAllQuestionsTable>> tPages;
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
protected void Answer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["SeekPressed"] = "pressed";
    tPages = new Dictionary<string, List<DisplayAllQuestionsTable>>();
    string subTopic = SubTopicDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value;
    List<DisplayAllQuestionsTable> threadsByTopic = new List<DisplayAllQuestionsTable>();
    List<string> btns = new List<string>();

    foreach (var topicKeys in postsByTopic)
    {

           if (topicKeys.Key == subTopic)
            {
                foreach (var item in postsByTopic[topicKeys.Key])
                {
                    questionNumber++;
                    maximumTopicPages++;
                    threadsByTopic.Add(item);//Adds All DisplayAllTables objects
                    //if there are 20 add a button.
                    if (maximumTopicPages == 20)
                    {
                        tPages.Add(tPage++.ToString(), threadsByTopic);//Add a number to the page each time, with a DisplayTable object  
                        //new Button
                        Button pgs = new Button();//Create New Topic
                        pgs.Width = 20;                        
                        pgs.Command += obtainTopicsPerPage_Click;
                        pgs.CommandName = tPage.ToString();
                        pgs.Text = tPage.ToString();

                        btns.Add(tPage.ToString());
                        buttons.Add(pgs);
                        maximumTopicPages = 0;
                        threadsByTopic.Clear();
                    }

                }//number of questions per page
                if (!tPages.ContainsKey((questionNumber / 20).ToString()))
                {
                    tPages.Add((questionNumber / 20).ToString(), threadsByTopic);//If A button is missing add it.
                }
            }
```

Way the buttons are added to the table:

```
    void MyButtonTable()
{

    TableRow myTableRow = new TableRow();
         HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();

    form.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");


    Page.Controls.Add(form);

    foreach (var item in buttons)
    {
        TableCell myTableCell = new TableCell();
        form.Controls.Add(item);
        myTableCell.Controls.Add(item);
        myTableRow.Cells.Add(myTableCell);

    }

    Table2.Rows.Add(myTableRow);
    Page.Controls.Add(Table2);
}
```

Comment: What is buttons ? please post your form design ?

Comment: It is a simple List. see above

Answer (score 2):

Are you adding your buttons to the Page afterwards?
Also, if you do not specify an ID to your buttons, they will be given one automatically in the form of ctlXXX

Comment: You should care because you said "I have no ctl02.. Why do i get that mistake?".  Locksfree explained why. If you don't specify IDs, they will be automatically assigned in the form of ctlXXX.

Answer (score 1):

What is in the .aspx file?  Specifically, what is the 'buttons' control? My guess is, it is a placeholder or panel or something similar. In that case, you need to add this to your .aspx file:

```
...
<body>
<form runat="server">
...
</form>
</body>
...
```

That should fix it.

ASP.NET needs to have the `<form>` tag managed by the server in order to use server side controls on your page. If your page already has a `<form>` tag on it somewhere, you can just add `runat="server"` to that tag and it will fix it. (That assumes the 'buttons' control that you're trying to add the dynamically created button into -- the placeholder or panel or whatever -- is itself between the `<form>...</form>` tags.)

Comment: Buttons is a list..i said i feed them into a list  ..But i already have a form running at server..and it doesnt fix it.  <div align="center" runat="server" >
                             <form id="form1" runat="server"> .. again..buttons isnt a control

Comment: You can't assign the `runat="server"` attribute problematically. You must assign it via markup. The Attributes collection tells ASP.NET what attributes to render in the HTML that is sent to the client, and can only work on a tag that is interpreted on the server. But ASP.NET doesn't know that it is supposed to be interpreting the <form> tag on the server unless you add `runat="server"` in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if "buttons" (I think is a placeholder) is inside a div or a tag with runat="server"

**update**

If I understand you can try something like this:

```
HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();

form.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
form.Controls.Add(buttons);

Page.Controls.Add(form);
```

(untested)

Comment: well, how do i put a div tag programmatically around them?

Comment: If you post your aspx html page I can give you an idea.

Comment: I could, the problem, is that i place there almost nothing, everything is generated programmatically.. i put a table and called it "Table2" then did Table2.Rows.Add(... and Page.Controls.Add(Table2). To the table  cells i added all the buttons.. Table2. runs at server

Comment: A page can have only one server-side Form tag.- got that. see how i put my buttons into the table above

Comment: Ok you have a already a form! So you don't need to add a form like in my answer! I'm trying to look at your code!

Comment: Here is part of the table markup:      <div align="center" runat="server">                  <asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="server">
        </asp:Table>
                     <br />         <br />         <br />         <br />
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Its working....

Please add your new button control into **from**

```
 protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button objButton = new Button();
        objButton.Text = "New Button";
        objButton.ID = "randomButton";
        form1.Controls.Add(objButton);                   
    }
```

Here **form1** -> form name available into .aspx file and objButton is button object.